# pygame image not showing

Tags: python, pygame

I have just started learning pygame. I try to display a bmp image at the bottom center of the pygame console display. There isn't any compilation error. Greatly appreciated if anyone tell me my error. I couldn't figure out where went wrong.

Code below where I load the image. The image is 64*64

```py
import pygame

class Ship():

    def __init__(self, screen):
        self.screen = screen

        self.image = pygame.image.load('images/rocket_small.bmp')
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.screen_rect = screen.get_rect()

        self.rect.centerx = self.screen_rect.centerx
        self.rect.bottom = self.screen_rect.bottom

    def blitme(self):
        self.screen.blit(self.image, self.rect)
```

Code below is where I run the screen. The screen size is 1200*800

```py
import sys
import pygame

from settings import Settings
from ship import Ship

def run_game():
    # init a window
    pygame.init()

    ai_settings = Settings()

    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((ai_settings.screen_width, ai_settings.screen_height))
    pygame.display.set_caption("Alien Invasion")

    ship = Ship(screen)

    # main loop
    while True:

        # for mouse and keyboard input
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                sys.exit()

        screen.fill(ai_settings.bg_color)
        ship.blitme

        # pygame.display.update()
        pygame.display.flip()

run_game()
```

This is my pygame and python3 version

> pygame 2.0.0.dev6 (SDL 2.0.10, python 3.8.0)

Comment: The parentheses `()` are missing: `ship.blitme()`

Comment: OMG, thank you so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is another way you can load images

```
import pygame
pygame.init()
player = pygame.image.load("player.png")

pygame.display.update()
```

the ("player.png") part make sure that your sprite is in your project and your sprite name might be different such as ("snowman.png")